# Pseudorandom number generator in C - seeding with time functions

Tags: c, random, compiler-construction, numbers, generator

So I'm attempting to create a pseudorandom number generator that will return a RN in a specified range for use later in my program.

Unfortunately, my compiler (gcc) will not recognize the type "time_t", the function "time()", etc. I thought I had included the right headers - but still having errors compiling. I may just be tired, but Googling the error didn't result in helpful information - so I turn to the great stackoverflow. My apologies if the problem simple and I just overlooked it...

my include statements:

```
#include "param.h"
#include "mmu.h"
#include "x86.h"
#include "proc.h"
#include "spinlock.h"
#include "pstat.h"
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
```

The RNG:

```
static int random_range (unsigned int min, unsigned int max){
    // Get value from system clock and place in seconds variable
    time_t seconds;
    // Convert seconds to a unsigned integer.
    time(&seconds);
    // Set seed
    srand((unsigned int) seconds);

    int base_r = rand(); 
    if (RAND_MAX == base_r) return random_range(min, max);
      // now guaranteed to be in [0, RAND_MAX) 
        int range       = max - min,
        int remainder   = RAND_MAX % range,
        int bucket      = RAND_MAX / range;
      // There are range buckets, plus one smaller interval within remainder of RAND_MAX 
        if (base_random < RAND_MAX - remainder) {
            return min + base_random/bucket;
        }

    else return random_in_range (min, max);

}
```

compiler errors relating to the above - not all since I'm sure I'm missing some include statement, or similar:

```
kernel/proc.c:9:18: error: time.h: No such file or directory
kernel/proc.c:10:20: error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
kernel/proc.c:11:19: error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
kernel/proc.c: In function ‘random_range’:
kernel/proc.c:31: error: ‘time_t’ undeclared (first use in this function)
kernel/proc.c:31: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
kernel/proc.c:31: error: for each function it appears in.)
kernel/proc.c:31: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘seconds’
```

Comment: I think your compiler config may have a problem since it is apparently not even recognizing standard lib headers.

Comment: Why it's not including the header files, I have no idea...

Comment: I'm using xv6's included make file. Didn't adjust anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahhh... I think I got it:

xv6 can't use the stdlib function calls. I'll have to create my own random function.

Any suggestions? Please link me... I know that there's something out there called "something"-twister that's supposed to be good.

Comment: Mersenne twister is what you are looking for. Many links to source code at http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/VERSIONS/C-LANG/c-lang.html

Comment: Yes, that. I should probably sleep... Wait, no - there's coding to do!

Comment: Sleep now and try again in the morning. It will work better. It's Saturday night - you should be past your [Ballmer peak](https://xkcd.com/323/).

Comment: Oh, if only alcohol was involved in my decision making right now... 

Thank you, Floris, for the link. And <3 to Randall Munroe.

Answer (score 2):

You're compiling the file:

```
kernel/proc.c
```

So you're clearly working in the kernel. You may not be aware of this but the standard libraries **do not exist** and cannot be compiled into the kernel.

`stdio.h`, `stdlib.h`, and `time.h` do not exist in the environment of the kernel development so that's why you get the error.

You need `#include <linux/time.h>` for time stuff... not that it helps you much since as you said, the `rand()` set of functions won't work in the kernel.

Now if you include `#include <linux/random.h>` Then you can use

```
void get_random_bytes(void  *buf, int nbytes);
```

This interface will return  the requested number of random bytes and place it in the buffer. So effectively you can do:

```
int i;

get_random_bytes(&i, sizeof i);
```

If you've ever see the entry `/dev/random` or `/dev/urandom`, this is the kernel side of that filesystem entry.

Comment: I became aware of the stdlib issues in the kernel after a little while - but am still looking for a solution to my RNG issue. Will try your implementation in the morning. Too exhausted to continue right now.

Comment: @katiea - any luck? I could provide a better example if you need one. reviewing my description, it wasn't be best, but also was written too late at night. :)

Comment: Hi Mike! your solution made sense, but I went with a different implementation.

Thanks!

Comment: I moved on to a different issue, but this project was due today. I ended up not having a functioning project... I'm just trying to figure out where I went wrong. If you want to try and help, it's located here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22006642/xv6-scheduler-proc-never-0

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are tired. Notice that your compiler can't even seem to find `<stdio.h>`:

```
kernel/proc.c:10:20: error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
```

You need to try to get a simple "hello world" program to compile - right now the compiler is apparently looking in the wrong place for the include files. You can usually put a `-I some/path` to tell the compiler where to look for include files…  Can you show your compile command?

Is it possible that the makefile you have includes `-nostdinc` flag? That is typically done when you are compiling kernel code… see http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html

Comment: Using the standard xv6 make file - I cannot change this file. It must work with the included make file. If I remove the RNG - it compiles and runs... Maybe I'm putting the func in the wrong place.

Comment: Are you saying that the compiler only complains about inability to find include files when you have your function definition in this file? Or is it OK when you don't include this source file in the build? Have you tried `#include "stdio.h"` instead of using `<>`?

Comment: See my answer below that I posted. The issue was including stdlib in the first place while editing the xv6 kernel files.

Answer (score 0):

Just based from the errors you've posted, it is evident that your compiler cannot find the standard library header files. That is the root of the problem.